# How can I avoid having too many arguments in Spring Java controllor

Tags: java, spring-mvc, parameters, controller, parameter-passing

In my Spring web application:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = NEW)
public String addProduct(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam(required = false) String description,
                         @RequestParam String price, @RequestParam String company, ModelMap model,
                         @RequestParam(required = false) String volume, @RequestParam(required = false) String weight) {
    try {
        productManagementService.addNewProduct(name, description, company, price, volume, weight);
        model.addAttribute("confirm", PRODUCT_ADDED);
        return FORM_PAGE;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, INVALID_VALUE);
        model.addAttribute("error", INVALID_VALUE);
        return FORM_PAGE;
    } catch (InvalidUserInputException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
        model.addAttribute("error", e.getMessage());
        return FORM_PAGE;
    }
}
```

What are the possible ways to reduce/bind total number of arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

create Form Class i.e

```
class MyForm{
String name;
String price;
String description;
...
 // Getters and setters included
}
```

and do like

```
@RequestMapping(value = NEW)
public String addProduct(@ModelAttribute MyForm myForm)
```

instantiation of `MyForm` and binding of request parameters to its properties and adding to ModelMap is done by spring behind the scenes.

Source: [Spring Docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods)

> An @ModelAttribute on a method argument indicates the argument should
>   be retrieved from the model. If not present in the model, the argument
>   should be instantiated first and then added to the model. Once present
>   in the model, the argument's fields should be populated from all
>   request parameters that have matching names. This is known as data
>   binding in Spring MVC, a very useful mechanism that saves you from
>   having to parse each form field individually.

Comment: @GriffeyDog: so you are saying that i need to create the model in last action and add it to model map and pass it to jsp page where i'll encapsulate it and then submit the request to addProduct action

Answer (score 3):

Create a `class`, encapsulate all the attributes in that class and then accept that class object as your `@ModelAttribute`. Something like:

```
public class MyData {

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private String price;

    private String company;

    private String volume;

    private String weight;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public String getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public void setVolume(String volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public String getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(String weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

}
```

And then modifying your addProduct method like this:

```
public String addProduct(@ModelAttribute MyData myData, ModelMap model)
```

Comment: Put a note for the names of the parameters and their getters/setters.

Comment: where encapsulation will be done? at view level? If so then could you describe a bit.

Comment: @Prashant You just need to create a class and ecapsulate the attributes in that class as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @JunedAhsan: I got concept of encapsulating in a class but my confusion is that when data is submitted on form. and sent in a request. then it'll be approaching to relevant controller. so in this operation of transmitting tyhe data from jsp page to controller where do we do the encapsulation to myData class. in jsp page?

Comment: @Juned, You need to do this as a `ModelAttribute` not a `RequestParam`.

Comment: @GriffeyDog: so you are saying that i need to create the model in last action and add it to model map and pass it to jsp page where i'll encapsulate it and then submit the request to addProduct action.

Comment: @JunedAhsan: Thanks for your help Juned. I've understood it now